# change button icon filling color on row action click in LWC datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, html

I have this below lwc data-table in which i have a column with slds icon. these icons are button icons which are clickable .

On the icon button click i am calling **callRowAction** function in which i am trying to change the icon color filing from slds-icon-text-warning to slds-icon-text-error.

after clicking i think the value is changing, but the updated color is not getting refresh on the page.

How to refresh the color on the page

[image]

HTML -

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable key-field="id" columns={cols} data={data} onrowaction={callRowAction}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

JS -

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
     @track cols = [
 
        { 
          type: 'button-icon', typeAttributes: { 
            iconName: { 
              fieldName: 'iconPriority' }, name: 'priority', iconClass: { 
                fieldName: 'iconPrioritycss' }, variant: 'bare' }, initialWidth: 30 
                },
        {
            fieldName: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        }
    ];

     @track data = [
        {
            id: 1, name: 'Opportunity 1', iconPriority: 'utility:favorite', iconPrioritycss: 'slds-icon-text-warning'
        },
        {
            id: 2, name: 'Opportunity 2', iconPriority: 'utility:favorite', iconPrioritycss: 'slds-icon-text-warning'
        }
    ]

    callRowAction(event) {
        this.tskId = event.detail.row.Id;
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        if (actionName === 'priority') {
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row)).id)
            this.changeiconcolor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row)).id);
        }
    }

    changeiconcolor(num) {
      alert(num)
      console.log(this.data[num - 1])
     this.data[num - 1].iconPrioritycss = 'slds-icon-text-error'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the framework does not know when you change the inner property of the array. So you need to reinitiate the `data` property.

Also, you don't need to do JSON stringify in the `callRowAction` just pass the row id in the other function.

Make the below changes in two functions `callRowAction` and `changeiconcolor`

```
callRowAction(event) {
  this.tskId = event.detail.row.Id;
  const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
  if (actionName === "priority") {
    this.changeiconcolor(event.detail.row.id);
  }
}

changeiconcolor(num) {
  this.data[num - 1].iconPrioritycss = "slds-icon-text-error";
  this.data = [...this.data]
}
```

[Check the live playground example here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/B26fj78bGjBqlwALwgZz/src/app.js?p=stories)

Comment: thanks rahul....

Comment: Remember though, you can use track instead of manually copying the array.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah that's what I thought but OP has already used track. but it didn't work somehow.

Comment: FYI, here's the [replication of the problem](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/tbeVJDaAYiMBldKhk0AM/src/app.js?p=stories). I'm going to try to bring this to someone's attention. In the interim, copying the array is necessary. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: There's an [open bug](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/1616) for this already, so not much more we can do at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I was not sure that it was a bug, but now I know.